# Kotlin: Check if a KTypeProperty1 is a data class

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Using reflection I can iterate through my attributes:

```
data class AnotherDataClass(
    val property: String,
    val dataClass: DataClass
)


AnotherDataClass::class.memberProperties.filter {
    return it::class.isData
}
```

But `it::class.isData` is always false since the type of `it` is `jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl`. Is there a way to check if this class is a data class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
AnotherDataClass::class.memberProperties.filter {
    (it.returnType.classifier as? KClass<*>)?.isData ?: false
}
```